# Java Swing using CardLayout with "Card" composed of multiple JPanels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, cardlayout

I am attempting to use `cardlayout` for 2 separate `JPanels`, the first `JPanel` that I will be using in the cardlayout is my "Main menu" panel which is a simple `JPanel` with 2 buttons on it.

The second `JPanel` that I am using in my `cardlayout` is my "Garage Manager" panel, which is actually a `JPanel` composed of 5 JPanels.

My first question is, is what I'm attempting to do even possible since my "Garage Manager" panel is a panel made up of multiple JPanels?

If this is possible, can you explain or point me in the right direction as to why my code is not displaying either of the "cards" in my cardlayout?

It will only let me attach one image to this post since I am new here, so I have attached an image of what my "GarageManager" Panel **should** look like.

I will try and attach an image of what my "mainMenu" panel **should** look like as well as an image of the gray frame I actually get when I run my code in the comments or on this post after I post it.

I am fairly new to programming and swing so any constructive criticism or help with my code is greatly appreciated.

[What garageManager should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj2in.png)

Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    window window = new window();
    window.createGUI();
   }
}
```

window.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class window {
//Create default frame to be used
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Parking Garage Manager");

//JPanel to be used as card panel
JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel();
CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

//2 main JPanels to be used in cardLayout
JPanel mainMenuPanel = new mainMenu();
JPanel garageManagerPanel = new garageManager();

//frame height and width
private final int frameWidth = 1600;
private final int frameHeight = 1000;

public void createGUI() {
    cardPanel.setLayout(cardLayout);
    cardPanel.add(garageManagerPanel, "GMP");
    cardPanel.add(mainMenuPanel, "MMP");
    cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "MMP");
    frame.getContentPane().add(cardPanel);

    //manage frame essentials.
    frame.setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }// end of createGUI class
}// end of window class
```

garageManager.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class garageManager extends JPanel {
//JPanels for garage manager card.
JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 300, 50));
JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
JPanel westPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JButton backToMainMenu = new JButton("Back To Main Menu");
JButton compact = new JButton("Compact");
JButton fullSize = new JButton("Full Size");
JButton motorcycle = new JButton("Motorcycle");
JButton handicap = new JButton("HandiCap");
JLabel welcomeLabel = new JLabel();
JLabel vehicleChoice = new JLabel();
JLabel closestSpots = new JLabel();
private final int frameWidth = 1600;
private final int frameHeight = 1000;

public garageManager() {
    setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    // manage north panel
    northPanel.setSize(frameWidth, (int)(frameHeight * 0.2));
    northPanel.setLocation(0,0);
    northPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.gray));

    welcomeLabel.setText("Welcome To The Parking Garage System");
    welcomeLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 50));
    welcomeLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
    northPanel.add(welcomeLabel);

    // manage south panel
    southPanel.setSize(frameWidth, (int)(frameHeight * 0.2));
    southPanel.setLocation(0, (int)(frameHeight * 0.8));
    southPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.gray));
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    vehicleChoice.setText("What Type of Vehicle Will You Be Parking?");
    vehicleChoice.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
    vehicleChoice.setForeground(Color.blue);

    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    constraints.ipady = 50;
    constraints.gridwidth = 10;
    constraints.gridheight = 2;
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    southPanel.add(vehicleChoice, constraints);

    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraints.ipady = 20;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.gridx = 2;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    fullSize.setForeground(Color.cyan);
    southPanel.add(fullSize, constraints);

    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraints.ipady = 20;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.gridx = 4;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    compact.setForeground(Color.orange);
    southPanel.add(compact, constraints);

    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraints.ipady = 20;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.gridx = 6;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    motorcycle.setForeground(Color.RED);
    southPanel.add(motorcycle, constraints);

    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraints.ipady = 20;
    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.gridx = 8;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    handicap.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    southPanel.add(handicap, constraints);

    // manage west panel
    westPanel.setSize((int)(frameWidth * 0.2), (int)(frameHeight * 0.6));
    westPanel.setLocation((int)(frameWidth * 0.8), (int)(frameHeight * 0.2));
    westPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.gray));

    westPanel.add(backToMainMenu);

    // manage east panel
    eastPanel.setSize((int)(frameWidth * 0.2), (int)(frameHeight * 0.6));
    eastPanel.setLocation(0, (int)(frameHeight * 0.2));
    eastPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.gray));

    closestSpots.setText("The closest spots available are...");
    closestSpots.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 17));
    closestSpots.setForeground(Color.blue);

    eastPanel.add(closestSpots);

    // manage center panel
    centerPanel.setSize((int)(frameWidth * 0.6), (int)(frameHeight * 0.6));
    centerPanel.setLocation((int)(frameWidth * 0.2), (int)(frameHeight * 0.2));
    centerPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.gray));

    add(northPanel, "North");
    add(southPanel, "South");
    add(eastPanel, "East");
    add(westPanel, "West");
    add(centerPanel, "Center");
 }
}
```

mainMenu.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class mainMenu extends JPanel {

JButton enterGarage = new JButton("Enter Parking Garage");
JButton leaveGarage = new JButton("Pay and Leave Garage");

private final int frameWidth = 1600;
private final int frameHeight = 1000;

public mainMenu() {
    setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    setVisible(true);
    initComponets();
}// end of mainMenu()

public void initComponets() {
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    enterGarage.setSize(300, 300);

    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraints.ipadx = 50;
    constraints.ipady = 50;
    constraints.gridwidth = 3;
    constraints.gridheight = 10;
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    this.add(enterGarage, constraints);

    leaveGarage.setSize(300, 300);

    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraints.ipadx = 50;
    constraints.ipady = 50;
    constraints.gridwidth = 3;
    constraints.gridheight = 10;
    constraints.gridx = 5;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    this.add(leaveGarage, constraints);
  }// end of initComponets()
}// end of mainMenu Class.
```

Comment: Here is a link to what the mainMenu class should look like
http://imgur.com/MZhnqQC

Here is a link to what is actually displayed when I run all of my code
http://imgur.com/ZdbXzLD

Comment: `My first question is, is what I'm attempting to do even possible since my "Garage Manager" panel is a panel made up of multiple JPanels?` - it doesn't matter how many panels is on the GarageManager. It is only the top level panel that is swapped, so all the child panels get swapped as well. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a working example to get you started.

Comment: So the idea of debugging is to start small and then go big. So first get a simple example working with two panels that only contain a single component. If you have problems then you have a simple [mcve] to post. We are not interested in reading all the code of your real application. Then once you understand the basic concept you replace one of the panels with a more complex panel. Once that works you replace the other panel. As long as you have the top level design correct, then number of components on each swappable panel becomes irrelevant.

Comment: *"Here is a link to what the mainMenu class should look like.."" Holy crap-spackle! I was about to embed those images, but it does not take an image of 3200 pixels in size to represent two buttons or a blank GUI. See [How to create great screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831)

Comment: camickr - Okay thank you. That is what I had thought to be true with the child panels swapping with the top level panel, but wasn't 100% sure. Therefore, something is obviously wrong with the way I have went about attempting this. I will read more on how to use the layout.

Comment: I figured out that I was actually using cardLayout correctly. What was causing my problem of just a blank grey screen was in my window class I was setting a borderLayout on my frame that I believe was overriding the cardLayout that I had set on my container panel. Don't know why I had set a layout on my JFrame but deleting that one line of code fixed all of my problems.